# Is it possible to scan for Bluetooth devices that are bonded with another device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using the Android Bluetooth API to scan RSSI on nearby devices. I need to get the signal intensity of the devices even if they're connected with another device, i.e a smartwatch that's connected to another cellphone. Is it possible to scan this?

To scan the devices I'm using:

```java
private final BroadcastReceiver bReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Create a new device item
                DeviceItem newDevice = new DeviceItem(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), "false");
                // Add it to our adapter
                mAdapter.add(newDevice);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Unfortunately to my knowledge that is not possible. Ble works by having devices which are "detectable" meaning they are in a state to be seen. However, when they are connected with a device they are not detectable / scan-able. So I don't think it is possible. That being said you can still scan for detectable devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas. I will look for an alternative.

Comment: No problem the main reason why is for security so people can advertise there location but only when they want to.

Answer (score 0):

Despite current comments suggest otherwise, it is indeed possible to as you asked, "scan for Bluetooth devices that are bonded with another device"

What your really asking is: can a Bluetooth device continue to advertise and be discovered even after bonding with other devices?

The answer is nuanced.  There is nothing that prevents a bonded device to continue to advertise and bond with yet addition devices. But what is often chosen is for a device to not continue advertising after it makes a *connection* to a device.

All a bond is, is a device remembering the security information exchanged during a successful pairing. Therefore if say device A scans and then bonds with the advertising device B, the bond record belongs to device A. So as long as device B continues advertising, it is discoverable by other Bluetooth devices (and bond together if it so chooses)

But as mentioned, in practice, often after a bond, devices will connect to that device, and most devices do not want/have a necessity to connect with any other devices (which it could if it was programmed to) so it will most often cease advertising upon connection.

Not saying any smart watches will advertise after bonding, but that is an implementation detail of a smart watch, not a specification of Bluetooth